# jquery live method in combobox interaction

Tags: jquery, combobox, live, onchange

I am trying to do the next thing in Jquery.
I have 2 comboboxes and i want to make sure that their selected values is identical. If user chooses a value in one of the combo like the other one, i want to alert "invalid op" and set the combo selected value to its previous value.
so i wrote:

```
$("#SelectGroupMargin").live("onchange", function() {
   // save the value before the change in case the change is invalid
   var valBeforeChange = $("#SelectGroupMargin").val();
   var currentLimitedRuleVal =  $("#SelectGroup").val();
   var newFillerRule= $(this).val();

   // check that the new value does not colide with the value of the limited rule
   // if it does colide alert the user and return to the former value
   if (currentLimitedRuleVal == newFillerRule) {
     alert("invalid op");
     $("#SelectGroupMargin").text(valBeforeChange);
   } 
});
```

but i have few problems:
1)onchange doesn't respond - just click and focusout 
2) newFillerRule always identical to valBeforeChange

Do you have better idea/shorter any advice
thank u

Comment: I think some acceptable grammar and spelling could help you out a little more. We value well formed questions highly here.

Comment: 4 spaces. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, but the FAQ here won't tell you that sentences start with capital letters.

Comment: @Joseph Silvashy: Not every person in the world speaks fluent English. Some people have problems expressing what they want to express in a foreign language. There is no need to attack.

Comment: Fair enough, but  I didn't know leet speak was more popular than english. I suppose I'd be more important to me if I was addressing a mostly speaking community looking for help.

Comment: @Joeseph Silvashy. Since when did 'leet' appear in the Oxford dictionary. Eat your own dog food.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `change` as opposed to `onchange` in the `live()` method. Also, if my memory serves me correctly, you'll need jQuery 1.4+ to use `live` with the change event, as code was only implemented in 1.4+ to handle delegation for the `change` event.

In terms of comparing the newly selected value to the last selected value, you might consider storing the selected value for the   using [`$.data()`](http://%20api.jquery.com/jQuery.data%20) - then you can compare the value after the change event with the value stored in $.cache (where $.data() stores values) and do the necessary. You could also implement it using a closure too.

Comment: Tested it, it works as expected concerning your question. I'd look over your syntax carefully, perhaps you have other code affecting the sample you've given us.

Comment: It does work with 1.4+. How do i get the value that was selected before the change?

Comment: You'd need to observe the `click` event on it, get it's value, then compare it to the value after it's been changed. In fact you don't need the `live()` function at all in your case.

Answer (score 0):

$("#SelectGroupMargin") is the same as $(this) in the context of that function. And use "change" for the live call